# How to change the target button class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm quite new to vue and can't figure out how to do it, i have several buttons and i need to select only one when clicked, i did it via

```
:class="isActive ? 'on' : 'off'"
v-on:click ="isActive = !isActive"
```

but this activates all the buttons, then I understand that I need to somehow distinguish the target button from the non-target one, but I can’t figure out how to do this. I can't find suitable implementation examples can you provide code examples

```
data() {
        return {
            isActive: true,
            color: ‘’,
        };
    },
<template>
      <div id="btn-box">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn off"
          @click="component='BorderLeftComonent', toggleShowPopup()">
          <div
            style="padding: 0 5px; width: 25px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 25px;"
            :style="{ 'border-left': `4px solid ${color}` }">A</div>
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn off"
          @click="component='TextBalloonComponent'">
            <div
            class="bubble"
            style="margin: 0 auto; width: 25px; font-size: 25px;">A</div>
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn off"
          @click="component='DashedComponent'">
          <div
            style="border: 4px dashed #f5d018; margin: 0 auto; width: 45px; font-size: 25px;">A</div>
        </button>
      </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Create multiple states.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Take a look at official docs [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) for v2.x and earlier. For Vue 3, [Class and Style Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-to-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Syntax:

```
:class="isActive ? 'on' : 'off'"
v-on:click ="isActive = !isActive"
```

Correct Syntax (using [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html)):

```
:class="{ 'on': isActive, 'off': !isActive }"
@click="isActive = !isActive"
```

OR this, and take a look at the example below:

```
:class="{ 'on': isActive, 'off': !isActive }"
@click="toggle"
```

Define the `@click` event `toggle` in the [methods](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#method-handlers) as this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- these buttons have `:class` binding and `@click` event -->
  <button :class="{ 'on': isActive, 'off': !isActive }" @click="isActive = !isActive">Toggle</button> OR
  <button :class="{ 'on': isActive, 'off': !isActive }" @click="toggle">Toggle</button> OR

  <!-- these buttons just have `@click` event -->
  <button @click="isActive = !isActive">Toggle</button> OR
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button> OR

  <!-- these buttons do not (have class and event binding) do anything -->
  <button>Toggle</button> OR
  <button>Toggle</button>

  <p v-if="isActive">{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<script>
  let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      isActive: true,
    },
    methods: {
      toggle() {
        this.isActive = this.isActive ? false : true
      }
    },
  })
</script>

<style scoped>
  /*simply styling your classes*/
  
  button {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: hsl(205, 46.5%, 73.5%);
    background-color: hsl(205, 14%, 28%);
  }
  
  .on {
    color: green;
  }
  
  .off {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: anyway, it changes class for all buttons, but how can I make the class change only on one button, without using v-for?

Comment: I have updated my code snippet. Be alert! when binding classes `:class="{...}"` and events `@click="..."`. All buttons have the same style, but only the first and second buttons will bind both the `on` and `off` classes and the `@click` events.

Comment: So, bind the classes `:class="{ 'on': isActive, 'off': !isActive }"` and events `@click="isActive = !isActive"` or `@click="toggle"` just on your target button(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use [v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for) directive to iterate over an array of button objects where each object includes it's own `isActive` property that can be toggled by the onclick event.

```html
<button
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="index"
      :class="button.isActive ? 'on' : 'off'"
      @click="button.isActive = !button.isActive"
    >
      <div :class="`btn btn-${button.type}`">{{ button.label }}</div>
</button>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      buttons: [
        {
          label: "A",
          isActive: false,
          type: "border-left",
        },
        {
          label: "A",
          isActive: false,
          type: "text-balloon",
        },
        {
          label: "A",
          isActive: false,
          type: "dashed",
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

```css
<style scoped>
.btn {
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.btn-border-left {
  border-left: 4px solid #f55;
}
.btn-dashed {
  border: 4px dashed #f5d018;
  width: 45px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, I've looked at this method, but the problem is that each button also has a nested div with inline styles inside and I don't understand how to write these elements in data buttons: []. I updated my template, you can see

Comment: It's not a problem with Vue.  Anything inside the `v-for` will be repeated.  If you nest a single div inside the `v-for`, every button will have a nested div.  Give each div it's own dynamic classname using a new object property in our data array, then you can specify the style for each within the `<style>` tags of your component.  I've updated my answer to show how this can be done.  Only thing I left out was the dynamic `${color}` the one div has. Adding that to the styling is a little complicated but [doable](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/passing-variables-to-css-on-a-vue-component)...

Comment: but without using v-for, is it possible, for example, to get the id of the button in data and check the id of the target button? Theoretically I can imagine how to implement this, but practically not very much!

Comment: Not sure I understand the purpose but without a v-for to dynamically render content you'll be setting everything in the template manually so you'll have to control what information gets passed around on a per button basis. on any button's `@click` handler you can give a function and pass whatever you want into that function including a button id.  `<button id="5" @click="someFunction(5)">` someFunction would then be able to tell what button called it.

Comment: well, but if you use your version with v-for, then how can I bind to each button individually the click that it should perform?

Comment: these are the buttons for dynamically switching components

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need a button group, a classic component in UI libraries.
Have a look at [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/button-groups/) one for example.

For example below, you have 4 buttons next to each other, and each button is highlighted when you click on it, see gif below.

[image]

And in your code, you have access to a property (here "text") that reflects which button is selected.
Code taken from the link above:

```
<v-btn-toggle
    v-model="text"
    tile
    color="deep-purple accent-3"
    group
  >
    <v-btn value="left">
      Left
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn value="center">
      Center
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn value="right">
      Right
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn value="justify">
      Justify
    </v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my task is not to use vuetify